# A function failes and a message appears only on Raspbery Pi OS

Tags: raspberry-pi, paclets, interpreter

I met a message such that,

`Get::noopen: Cannot open /home/pi/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/Interpreter-1.3.140.0/Kernel/32Bit/Interpreter.mx`

when I call the 'Interpreter[]' function. The directory '32Bit' in the message is not present on the directory tree but '64Bit' is instead.

And there is no message if I execute the same line of 12.1 on macOS.
It seems a bug on Raspberry Pi.

How can I fix it? or should I wait a fixed version of wolfram-engine for Raspberry Pi OS?

Comment: You should report this to Wolfram.

Comment: OK, but I don't know how to report.

Answer (score 3):

The latest Interpreter paclet on the public server is lacking the 32 bit support which causes that error. The new paclet will be released soon to get this fix.

Meanwhile we can do `PacletUninstall["Interpreter"]` to remove the downloaded paclet and run `$AllowInternet=False` to prevent automatic paclet update as workaround. Please note that `$AllowInternet` should set to True later in order to get paclet update.

Comment: Thank you, and your workaround was confirmed on my Raspberry pi.